# Spring elasticsearch java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

Trying to update a small experimental Spring Elasticsearch project to reflect changes in the 3.2.6 release [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.transport).

As noted: `TransportClient` is deprecated as of Elasticsearch 7 and will be removed in 8. Trying to reconfig to **High Level Rest Client**.

But getting the following errors

```
    Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticDatasource' defined in file [/Users/erichuang/Desktop/JE/00-Development/dev/lab/lab-elastic-search/lab-elastic-search/target/classes/com/elastic/labelasticsearch/config/ElasticDatasource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carElasticRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Error while for indexExists request: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest@b5d8ebb
    org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    com.elastic.labelasticsearch.LabElasticSearchApplication.main(LabElasticSearchApplication.java:15)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carElasticRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Error while for indexExists request: org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.get.GetIndexRequest@b5d8ebb
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796)

    ... 24 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: localhost/<unresolved>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:932)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1505)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:851)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1495)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1354)
at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1288)
...
... 63 common frames omitted
```

**Old setup (works)**

**ElasticSearchConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.elastic.labelasticsearch.repo")
public class ElasticSearchConfig  {
    private static final String esHost = "localhost";
    private static final int esPort = 9300;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws UnknownHostException {
        var transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY);
        transportClient.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(esHost), esPort));

        return transportClient;
    }

    @Bean(name ={"elasticsearchOperations", "elasticsearchTemplate"})
    public ElasticsearchOperations esTemplate() throws UnknownHostException {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
       return new RestTemplate();
    }

}
```

**New Setup**

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.elastic.labelasticsearch.repo")
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9300")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug resulting from as change in Java 14  in the `java.net.InetSocketAddress.toString()` method. This has been fixed in 4.0.RC2 (released yesterday).

**Edit:** I will backport this into the 3.2 branch as well

Comment: release candidates aren't published to maven central, you need to get it from the release repository (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.0.RC2/reference/html/#preface.metadata)

Comment: what releases did this fix make it into?  I have been waiting for this so we can move to JDK14 from the now unsupported JDK13

Comment: that's in 4.0.0.RELEASE and it will be in 3.2.8.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure your bean using this way that allow to separate the host port and http protocol used:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "*")
public class ElasticsearchClientConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String host;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.protocol}")
    private String protocol;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.username}")
    private String userName;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
    public RestHighLevelClient restClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(userName, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(host, port, protocol)).setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
    
        return client;
    }
}
```